Session not fetching correctly when check null it work as expected but not when fetching
When I try to fetch data of student at the end then the session of std_id is not being fetch half correctly.
Login
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult slogin(student s)
{
    student sv = db.students.Where(x => x.std_name == s.std_name && x.std_password == s.std_password).SingleOrDefault();

    //sc.scoree[0] = sv.std_id.ToString();
    //sc.scoree[1] = sv.std_name;

    if (sv == null)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Invalid User Name or Password!";
    }
    else
    {
        Session["std_id"] = s.std_id;
        return RedirectToAction("ExamDashboard");
    }

    return View();
}

In the below code when using debugging the if condition works as expected not entering inside if block, but after that this line takes value as 0 Debug.WriteLine("Student ID: " + studentId);
End Exam
public ActionResult EndExam(tbl_questions q)
{
    try
    {
        if (Session["std_id"] == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("slogin");
        }

        int studentId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["std_id"]);
        int score = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["score"]);
        int examId = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["examid"]);

        // Debugging statements to inspect values
        Debug.WriteLine("Student ID: " + studentId);
        Debug.WriteLine("Exam ID: " + examId);
        Debug.WriteLine("Score: " + score);

        // Check if any of the required data is null or 0
        if (studentId <= 0 || score < 0 || examId <= 0)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Error: Invalid data for exam creation.";
            return View();
        }

        tbl_setExam exam = new tbl_setExam();
        exam.exam_date = DateTime.Now;
        exam.exam_fk_stud = studentId;
        exam.exam_name = "Sample Exam"; // You may want to set a proper exam name
        exam.std_score = score;

        db.tbl_setExam.Add(exam);
        db.SaveChanges();

        ViewBag.Score = score; // You can pass the score to the view if needed

        return View();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Error: " + ex.Message;
        return View();
    }
}

I tried to debug but was unable to find the issue.
I'm trying to insert the end exam data into database but it isn't inserting any of the data.

Could you please tell me is there any other specific settings for the session inside the program.cs? Besides, I suggest you could check the browser's setting to make sure you enable the cookie.

did you mean to set the session value to the passed in "student" id?  Session["std_id"] = s.std_id;  (if so a user could possibly impersonate another user) Did you want sv.uid or sv.std_id instead?

@BrandonZhang No there is no settings related to session in program.cs file.

@browsermator what silly mistake i made you are right using sv.std_id instead s.std_id is works.

using more meaningful variable names can help, but we always make silly mistakes from time to time.

The silly mistake happens in this line
student sv = db.students.Where(x => x.std_name == s.std_name && x.std_password == s.std_password).SingleOrDefault();

Session["std_id"] = s.std_id;

Used sv.std_id instead s.std_id
